# Is there a workaround for ignored content_for blocks with caches_action and :layout => false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

When you use `caches_action :layout => false` in Rails 3, any content_for blocks that are populated in the cached view and used in your layout wind up empty. Is there any workaround for this?

E.g. in my application I have the following rather typical setup.

A helper method called from my views which sets the page title:

```
# application_helper.rb
def page_title(title)
    content_for(:page_title) { title }
end
```

A line in my layout file as follows

```
# application.html.erb
<head>
<title><%= yield(:page_title) %></title>
</head>
```

And in a view I might call

```
# index.html
<% page_title 'Hello!' %>
```

Of course, if you cache your action with `:layout => false`, this results in having blank page titles, since action caching ignores all content_for blocks.

Is there no workaround for this?  Action caching with `:layout => false` is so close to being brilliantly useful, but this glitch renders it quite awkward.

Other folks asking or commenting about this same issue:

1. http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/d8d72f050701d44b
2. http://www.golygon.com/2011/04/tips-and-tricks-in-ruby-on-rails/
3. https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4140-action-caching-with-caches_action-and-layout-false

And the [Rails documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/master/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper#content_for-instance_method) that notes this behavior:

"WARNING: content_for is ignored in caches. So you shouldn’t use it for elements that will be fragment cached."

Comment: This appears to be handled entirely by rails now.

Comment: Old post. How did you manage to action cache the page and handle the dynamic title in the end?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the way I got around this was to create a fragment cache of the parts of the header that are dependent on the content_for being populated.

so it looks something like this:

```
# application.html.erb
<head>
<% cache("#{request.env['PATH_INFO']}/header") do %>
    <title><%= yield(:page_title) %></title> 
<% end %>
```

so this cached fragment should be populated at the same time the action is cached.

Comment: Don't do this, the two caches (action and your fragment) won't necessarily always be there, depending on your cache store. One might be pushed out of the cache or expired sooner. I am still looking for a good solution to this, though. What i'm doing now is patching the action caching to store these things such as title, etc in a hash, marshalling it, and caching that whole thing. HOWEVER this fails occasionally, and is driving me absolutely insane.

Comment: Yes this is an important point, I currently use the file cache store and as such the two caches are stored in the same directory and I wipe the whole directory at once when clearing the cache for a record.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and used [this gist](https://gist.github.com/2485272) and it works fine!

Comment: ...it causes problem elsewhere though. I am not so sure I can recommend it any more.