# content_for works in development but not production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, content-for

I have a controller using caches_action

`controllers/bar_controller.rb:`

```
caches_action :bar, :layout => false
```

and in the view of this action, I'ill setting html title in layout.

`views/foo/bar.html.erb:`

```
<%= content_for :mytitle do "testing" end %>
```

this is my layout file:

`views/layouts/application.html.erb:`

```
<title><%= yield :mytitle %></title>
```

However, this only work in development. In production, it does not work.  Any idea is appreciated. thanks.

similar question: [Is there a workaround for ignored content_for blocks with caches_action and :layout => false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177011/is-there-a-workaround-for-ignored-content-for-blocks-with-caches-action-and-lay)

Comment: Caching is probably off in development.  When it *does* cache in production, you're telling it to ignore the layout, and with it, what would be rendered from `content_for`.

Comment: is content_for   ignored in caches?

Comment: If you yield the content_for in the layout and pass `:layout => false`, it seems so.  From [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Actions.html): "If you pass :layout => false, it will only cache your action content. That’s useful when your layout has dynamic information."

Answer (score 1):

Rails will simply ignore the content_for block in caching enabled environment. Use `ActionController::Filters` to compute the values and store those values in instance variables. Refer instance variables in layouts.